installing foundry on gitpod
please is there a way I can install or use foundry on Gitpod environment?
I tried installing wsl on my windows 10 but the command doesn't seem to be running.
so I want to use Gitpod environment for the mean time but I don't know how to install foundry on Gitpod

You can refer to this part of the Solidity Smart Contract Development course video, in which they've gone through the Foundry installation using Gitpod.
However, it's not ideal to use Gitpod for security reasons, so if you want to install Foundry in Windows via WSL, then you can refer to this answer.

alright thanks
I am aware that it is not safe, I am using it for practice only

I have watched this and I have open up the Gitpod, but how do i install all the dependecy, the tutorial was done in vsc, can i apply same to the Gitpod environment

I’m not sure though. Have you tried?
